# Saving records in a text file Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

this is my firts question in the page, and i'm new with Python 3, i'm using the head first book Programming to get into it. So my question is about saving formatted data into a text file, I've checked the code given by the book, and I wrote it as it is. But i get this error: 
**IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer**

My code is the next one:

```
def save_transaction(price, credit_card, description):
file = open ("transactions.txt","a")
file.write ("%s%07d\n" % (credit_card,price * 100, description))
file.close()

items = ["DONUT","LATTE","FILTER","MUFFIN"]
prices = [1.50,2.0,1.80,1.20]
running = True

while running:
    option = 1
    for choice in items:
        print(str(option)+"."+choice)
        option = option + 1
    print(str(option) + ". Quit")
    choice = int(input("choose an option: "))

if choice == option:
    running = False 
else:
    credit_card = input("credit card number: ")
    save_transaction(prices[choice - 1], credit_card, items[choice - 1])
```

The output must be something like this:

> 63827462387648320000220 LATTE
>
> 63827462387648320000180 FILTER

where the first 6 numbers are from the credit card, the 7 next ones are the price and then is the description.

I'm glad if you make me know what's wrong with this.Thanks buddies.

Comment: provide the full error Traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desarrollo Lap\Desktop\Python\Ejercicios Python.py", line 241, in <module>
    save_transaction(prices[choice - 1], credit_card, items[choice - 1])
  File "C:\Users\Desarrollo Lap\Desktop\Python\Ejercicios Python.py", line 223, in save_transaction
    file.write ("%s%07d\n" % (credit_card,price * 100, description))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Sorry I missed some arguments in this line:                                               file.write ("%s%07d%s\n" % (credit_card,price * 100, description))

Comment: It works fine to me, thank you for your time buddie